# How can I easily align elements of nested sequences in an equation?

Tags: math-mode, align, indentation

I'd like to have an equation where every next element of a sequence is on a new line and aligned with the previous element, but on multiple levels. It's like alignment in Lisp code, but in mathematical notation, not code listing.

If I use `align`, it's good for one level, but, if I use it for more levels, the other levels are aligned after the end of the longest line aligned at the first level. It works if I use `aligned` for every instance of every other level of alignment, but that becomes messy fast. A demonstration of that is at the end.

How can I easily align elements of nested sequences? That means that there wouldn't be much boilerplate code like an environment for every instance of alignment. I imagine that [elastic tabstops](https://nickgravgaard.com/elastic-tabstops/) would work well for that, but I haven't found and implementation of them in LATEX.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm, paperheight=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    A = ( \  & \mathrm{stuff}, \\
        & \begin{aligned}
            ( \  & z, \\
                & \begin{aligned}
                    ( \  & 1, \\
                        & 2 \  ),
                \end{aligned} \\
                & a, \\
                & b \  ),
            \end{aligned} \\
            & \mathrm{stuff2} \  )
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess, what isn't disclosed here, is that you want things to be easy (or automated). That is, you just want to type the input without all the code finagling. Is that correct? If so, there's not always an easy automatable solution to every problem. It depends on the scope of what you need. For example, you can buy parts for and build a car just to drive to your neighbour across the street, or just... well... walk across the street.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide what you think would be a viable input setup for your request that doesn't "get messy fast". It may be possible to untangle a structure and insert the necessary `\begin{aligned}`...`\end{aligned}` in the appropriate spots (given appropriate inputs). Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner What do you mean by “input setup”? Elastic tabstops (linked in the question) may provide the cleanest syntax for alignment, but they may be difficult to implement. I think that a simple thing would be that I could set anchors and spaces that would extend horizontally to the specified anchors (like `A = ( \anchor{1} a, \\ \align{1} b )`).

Comment: Have a look at [`tabstackengine`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine) as a start.

Comment: @Werner Thanks. That that may be what I want, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @Werner It seems that tabstackengine doesn't support overlapping columns. The environment `tabbing` works, but only in text mode, not math mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer this solution: The package nath offers `\wall`, which ensures that every following line begins under its place unless it's overridden by an other `\wall` or cancelled by `\return`, so pairs of `\wall` and `\return` can be nested.

```
\usepackage{nath}

…

\[
    A = ( \  \wall \mathrm{stuff}, \\
             ( \  \wall z, \\
                   ( \  \wall 1, \\
                        2 \  ), \return \\
                   a, \\
                   b \  ), \return \\
             \mathrm{stuff2} \  ) \\
\]
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It is possible to achieve this with `NiceArray` and `alignat*`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2.5cm}
        
        with \verb|NiceArray|
        
        $\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0mm}
        \begin{NiceArray}[t]{l l l l l l}
            1 & & & & &
            \\
            & 2 & & & &
            \\
            & & 3 & & &
            \\
            & & & 4 & &
            \\
            & & & & 5 &
            \\
            & & & & & 6
        \end{NiceArray}$
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace*{0.5cm}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2.5cm}
        
        with \verb|alignat*|
        
        \vspace*{-1.75\baselineskip}
        
        \begin{alignat*}{6}
            1 & & & & &
            \\
            & 2 & & & &
            \\
            & & 3 & & &
            \\
            & & & 4 & &
            \\
            & & & & 5 &
            \\
            & & & & & 6
        \end{alignat*}
    
    \end{minipage}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: In `NiceArray` and `alignat*`, the columns can't overlap, which results in that they are aligned after the end of the longest cell in the previous column, which is the same problem as in `align`.

Comment: @matj1 -- It's possible to embed the subsidiary environment `alignedat` within `alignat*`, so overlapping is quite possible, although verbose in the questioned example.